# UTF-8 locale drop

Tags: php, locale, gentoo

I've wrote this test script:

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
putenv('LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8');
putenv('LANG=ru_RU');
putenv('LANGUAGE=ru_RU');
setlocale (LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
for($i=0; $i<7; $i++){
    echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0) . "<br>\n";
    sleep(1);
}
?>
```

there is it output:

```
ru_RU.UTF-8
ru_RU.UTF-8
C
ru_RU.UTF-8
ru_RU.UTF-8
ru_RU.UTF-8
C
```

Why locale sometimes crashes? How to fix this?

Comment: Upgrade to latest stable PHP, still happening? File a bug with your OS and PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php...

> Warning: The locale information is maintained per process, not per
>   thread. If you are running PHP on a multithreaded server API like IIS
>   or Apache on Windows, you may experience sudden changes in locale
>   settings while a script is running, though the script itself never
>   called setlocale(). This happens due to other scripts running in
>   different threads of the same process at the same time, changing the
>   process-wide locale using setlocale().

I'm not a PHP expert but I guess an easy fix would be to start PHP with the right locale in the first place. You tagged this with gentoo. If you're using Gentoo but not Apache's mod_php then you should be able to use /etc/init.d/spawn-fcgi (which I wrote) from www-servers/spawn-fcgi to set LC_ALL. See /etc/conf.d/spawn-fcgi for details.